# What is the name of this method in Lebesgue integral

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, lebesgue-integral

1. I saw $$ \sum_{i \in \mathbb{Z}}
       \sum_{j \in \mathbb{Z}} f(i,j) =
       \sum_{k \in \mathbb{Z}} \sum_{(i,j)
       \in \{i+j =k, i, j \in \mathbb{Z}\}}
       f(i,j).$$ I was wondering what
   conditions for it to hold are? Is
   there a name for the method using
   such equality?
2. I was also wondering if $$\int_{x
       \in \mathbb{R}^n} \int_{y \in
       \mathbb{R}^n} f(x,y) du\, du =
       \int_{k \in \mathbb{R}^n}
       \int_{(x,y) \in \{x+y = k\}} f(x,y)
       du^2\, du$$ may also be true? What are
   conditions for it to hold?

   I am not sure if what I just wrote
   is mathematically correct.
   Especially, is the LHS two iterated
   integrals, each of which is an
   integral over $(\mathbb{R},
       \mathcal{B}, u)$. Is the RHS also two
   iterated integrals, but the one
   inside is an integral over product
   Lebesgue space $(\mathbb{R}^2,
       \mathcal{B}^2, u^2)$?

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Part $2$ of your post needs some heavy rewriting but both parts $1$ and $2$ are concerned with [Fubini's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fubini's_theorem). The net result is that if one series/integral converges for $|f|$, or if $f\ge0$, you can change the order of summation/integration and/or regroup things at will, the result will always exist and be the same no matter what ordering and regrouping method you used.

A starting point could be [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Absolute_convergence).

Answer (score 1):

Very late to the party... :) ... but it may be worthwhile to note that it is possible to prove this sort of "discrete" Fubini-Tonelli without the baggage of measure theory... and the technical "monotone families", which is the way that I'd learned... to prove the general version.